# How to make VS2012 stop generating CPS log?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, build

In order to debug the build process of some VS2012 project, I followed the steps outlined here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrewarnottms/archive/2012/06/07/enable-c-and-javascript-project-system-tracing.aspx

i.e. I added the suggested CPS config settings to `devenv.exe.config` file, asking for `Verbose` output. As expected, this made VS2012 to generate `devenv-cps.log` in `c:\temp` folder. Before making changes to `devenv.exe.config`, I saved a backup copy of the original file.

Once I figured out everything I wanted to figure out, I decided to revert `devenv.exe.config` to its original state by overwriting it from the aforementioned backup copy. However, to my great surprise, this did not disable the debug output and did not restore the original behavior of VS2012. The compiler still creates `devenv-cps.log` file in `c:\temp` folder every time I start VS2012 and updates it with verbose output every time I build my project.

I feel like I'm missing something very basic. Apparently, the CPS settings from `devenv.exe.config` became sticky somehow, e.g. they were saved somewhere else. So, how do I disable CPS debugging now and revert to the original behavior of VS2012?

Comment: Have you tried using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see if you can find where it is grabbing the info from?

Comment: @Mark Hall: I'm not sure what you mean and how Process Monitor fits in here. The info is dumped by VS2012 during project build (and the dump file is created by VS2012 at startup). There's no mystery of where this info is coming from. The question is why it keeps coming, even though I reverted the config file back to is original state.

Comment: You are saying that your replaced the config file with the old one, and it did not turn off your logging. I was suggesting that you monitor file and registry access to see where it is pulling the information from to enable the logging.

Comment: @Mark Hall: Oh, I see. That might work, although I'm sure VS2012 pulls in a huge amount of info at startup. Would be difficult to pick the relevant one. I did search the registry and the file system for the output file name, but it came up with nothing.

Comment: I know it would be like searching for a needle in a haystack, but it is the only thing I could think of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found out where that sticky setting was stored, but I was able to disable the log generation by  explicitly asking the VS2012 to stop doing it. This could be done by changing the

```
<add name="CPS" value="Warning"/>
```

line in `devenv.exe.config` file to

```
<add name="CPS" value="Off"/>
```

Comment: I thought I was having this problem at first, but it ended up being something else--two things, actually. First, I was editing the devenv.exe.config for VS2010 instead of VS2012 (smack). Second, I wasn't running my text editor in admin mode, so it wasn't saving my changes as expected (the directory requires admin rights to modify). Once I addressed those two things, deleting the info I'd added to system.diagnostics caused it to stop logging.